# Debug C# Windows Service without remote debugger

Tags: c#, debugging, windows-services

I have written a windows service in C#, this runs in Debug and Release mode on my desktop, but when it is installed on the server it doesn't work correctly.

It starts and stops just fine but the code doesn't execute. The permissions are seemingly set correctly on the file paths as SYSTEM, it is the Local System that is logged on as running the service.

I have installed remote debugger for VS2013, however in order to use this, the server requires a reboot, which cannot be done for the foreseeable future as this would compromise other services that are running.

Is there any way around this to find out what is causing the issue?

***In answer to question comments:***

There is logging and writing to debug, but none of the code appears to be executing which is why I'm stumped. As such none of the try/catch code is executing, the same security permissions are on this service's folders as other services that are working correctly. The `Debug.WriteLine`features aren't showing up within [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx).

Comment: You can write simple console app that will run the same code as the service to test if it is the code in production environment or just windows service specific rights.

Comment: Try adding some logging to your service.

Comment: _"Is there any way around this to find out what is causing the issue?"_ asking for a testing environment or adding enough logging.

Comment: Testing environment was VS2013 on my Local Machine, where everything is working, but I can't see what's causing the issue on the server.

Comment: Any mismatch or changes in Config file? Have you forgot anything related needs to be done in configuration file?

Comment: Sadly not, the XML config files that it's using are correct on the server. Everything has been replicated as is on my machine to the server. Permissions are the same as other services which are doing similar things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this sorted it - through trying every conceivable way that was on other posts.

1. Uninstall the service.
2. Deleting Bin and Obj.
3. Clean the solution.
4. Build the solution.
5. Set to Release.
6. Set back to Debug.
7. Re-installing the service on the server.